# Recover formatted partition from Ubuntu

Tags: partitioning, data-recovery

I have just made a great mistake while formatting one of my USB memories and instead of formatting the USB i formatted the hard drive partition where I have installed Windows 10. Is there any way to recover the old partition from Ubuntu?

If there is not, is there at least some way to recover part of the files?

Edit: to clarify, I am asking for tools that can be run from Ubutnu that can do the recovery.

Comment: Ubuntu is an OS, not a free repair tool kit for Windows. There are Windows or OS agnostic tools for that purpose, bot free and commercial, that are much easier to use for people without experience with the command line.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest tool for this is Photorec.

I suggest you follow this guide.

https://www.tecmint.com/photorec-recover-deleted-lost-files-in-linux/